# Prove that : $X_n \xrightarrow{\mathrm{a.s.}}0\iff \sum_n P(X_n>0) <\infty$

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence

> Let $(X_n)$ be a sequence of **independent integer-valued** (nonnegative integers) random variables
>
> Prove that  $X_n\xrightarrow{\mathrm{a.s.}} 0\iff \sum_n P(X_n>0) <\infty$

For the $\implies$ part, loosely speaking, $\sum_n P(X_n>0) <\infty\iff \prod_n (1-P(X_n>0))$ converges, and since the $X_n$ are integer-valued, this is the same as $\prod_n P(X_n=0)$ converges, which is true since $\prod_n P(X_n=0)= P(\bigcap_n (X_n=0))$.

To make this formal, I'd have to prove that for all but finitely many $n$, $P(X_n>0)\neq 1$ and $P(\bigcap_n X_n=0)\neq 0$. How can I do this ?

Is there another way to solve the problem ?

Comment: What is $X$ here?

Comment: @drhab it's $0$ of course, sorry for the typo

Comment: Hint: Borel-Cantelli lemma (both parts).

Comment: @Did I managed to prove the converse without that, since $P(\sup_{k\geq n} X_k\geq \epsilon) = P(\bigcup_{k\geq n} X_k\geq \epsilon) \leq \sum_{k\geq n} P(X_k \geq \epsilon)\leq \sum_{k\geq n} P(X_k >0) \to 0 $. I'll have a look with Borel-Cantelli for the $\implies$ part

Comment: Yeah--in other words, you rediscovered the standard proof of the easy part of Borel-Cantelli...

Comment: @Did with Borel-Cantelli, supposing that $\sum_n P(X_n>0) =\infty$, then $P(X_n>0 \text{ i.o })=1$, which implies that $\forall n, P(\bigcup_{k\geq n} X_k>0)=1$ ie $\forall n, P(\sup_{k\geq n} X_k>0)=1$. Then $\forall n, 1\leq \sum_N P( \sup_{k\geq n} X_k>\frac 1N)$. I'm stuck here.

Comment: Before jumping into rather mysterious considerations such as $\sup X_k>1/N$ (for integer valued random variables, what the...), you might want to think more about what the event $[X_n>0\ \text{i.o.}]$ really means.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I completely overthought this problem, thank you Did for pointing me in the right direction.

Actually, $\begin{align}X_n\xrightarrow{\mathrm{a.s.}} 0 &\iff P(\{w, X_n(w)\to 0\}) = 1 \\  &\iff P(\{w,\exists n, \forall k\geq n,X_n(w)=0\})=1 \text { because } X_n(w) \text{  is integer-valued} \\ &\iff P(\operatorname{liminf X_n=0)} =1 \\ &\iff P(X_n >0 \text{ i.o })=0 \end{align}$

If $\sum  P(X_n >0 ) < \infty$, $ P(X_n >0 \text{ i.o })=0$ hence $X_n\xrightarrow{\mathrm{a.s.}} 0$

If $\sum  P(X_n >0 ) = \infty$ $, P(X_n >0 \text{ i.o })=1$ and there is no convergence.