# $X_n \to 0$ a.s. if and only if $\sum_n \mathbb{P}(X_n = 1) < \infty$.

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence, solution-verification, borel-cantelli-lemmas

This post is quite similar to the question "[Prove that : $X_n \xrightarrow{\mathrm{a.s.}}0\iff \sum_n P(X_n>0) <\infty$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1771043/prove-that-x-n-xrightarrow-mathrma-s-0-iff-sum-n-px-n0-infty)", still slightly different. The statement is $X_n \to 0$ a.s. if and only if $\sum_n \mathbb{P}(X_n = 1) < \infty$. Here, $X_n, n \in \mathbb{N}$ is a sequence of independent random variables taking the values zero or one, with $\mathbb{P}(X_n = 1) = a_n$. I would like to know if my approach is correct.

**The approach**: Let $\limsup_{n \to \infty}A_n = \{A_n \ \text{i.o.}\}$. Assume $X_n \to 0$ almost surely, then
$$\mathbb{P}\left(\lim_{n \to \infty}X_n = 0\right) = 1,$$
which is equivalent to
$$\mathbb{P}\left(\limsup_{n \to \infty}\{|X_n| > \varepsilon\}\right) = \mathbb{P}(|X_n| > \varepsilon \ \text{i.o.}) = 0$$
for all $\varepsilon > 0$. By the Borel-Cantelli lemma, $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\mathbb{P}(|X_n| > \varepsilon) < \infty$ for all $\varepsilon > 0$. Meaning that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n < \infty$. \
Now assume $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n < \infty$, then by the Borel-Cantelli lemma $\mathbb{P}(X_n = 1 \ \text{i.o.}) = 0$. Since $X_n$ only takes value zero or one, $\{X_n = 1\}^c = \{X_n = 0\}$. So, the complement of
$$\{X_n = 1 \ \text{i.o.}\}^c = \left\{\bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{N}}\bigcap_{k \geq n}\{X_k = 0\}\right\} = \left\{\lim_{n \to \infty} X_n = 0\right\}.$$
So $\mathbb{P}(\lim_{n \to \infty}X_n = 0) = 1$, therefore $X_n \to 0$ almost surely.

Comment: wait, for 0-1 variables, you have $P(X>0) = P(X=1)$, so the question is just a duplicate of the one you liked..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it seems correct.

As an afterthought, note that the approach used in the question that you referenced can still be adapted to prove what you intended, in the following way:

1. Assume we have proved that $X_n \to 0$ a.s. is equivalent to $\sum_n \mathbb{P}(\{X_n>0\})<\infty$ (this can be done as was proved in the approved answer to the question referenced).
2. Then, note that $\mathbb{P}(\{X_n>0\}) = \mathbb{P}(\{X_n=1\})=a_n$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$ because as was noted during the question the random variables $X_n$ satisfy $\mathbb{P}(\{X_n\in\{0, 1\}\})=1$ for every $n\in\mathbb{N}$ so $\{X_n>0\}$ and $\{X_n=0\}$ differ by an event of probability $0$.
3. Combining both 1. and 2. we can deduce the equivalence we wished to prove.